# File load popup to appear with function, input is hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I want to file load popup to appear after I use function loadFile(), because myInput is hidden.

```
//HTML
<div id ="hideWhiteSpace" style="display:none">
    <input id="myInput" type="file"/>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript file example, onchange won't work cause i cant press the button.

```
//JS
function loadFile(){
 document.getElementById('myInput').onchange = function (e){
 //run code to load file into web.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it, just put this before onchange line:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').click();
```

I don't know if I should answer my own questions or delete the post if I got the answer.
Comment please.